# finding pattern data through sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I get particular pattern of data using sql query?

I have a string which has data like "Valid data: emp no - 123 emp age - 23 emp type - M."

So here I want whatever I have in `emp age` i.e. `23`. The string format will be same. I don't want to get `emp age` based on position as it can change ,is there any other way to get `emp age`?

Is a query which will find `emp age` tag in the string and then look three places after that tag to get `emp age` value?

Comment: sql query - which dialect? You have `MySQL`, `oracle` and `plsql` as tags. Please edit your post, remove the irrelevant tags, and save. Each dialect has different ways to solve your requirement.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are different database products. the fact that Oracle owns MySQL is irrelevant when it comes to tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is always the same you can try something like the following.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, 'emp age - ', -1), ' ', 1) AS Age 
FROM table;
```

Comment: in my string the value of age can change like it can be 23 or 2456,...but it will always be after emp no - .so i want a query which can give me sub string after emp no - till it finds another space.

Comment: if it's emp age - 23 or emp age - 65 or emp age - 2456 then it should return like this:

23
65
2456

Comment: The answer provided by @Mike Geise is the same solution I would suggest to you.  It doesn't care about the number of characters -it  takes everything after the last occurence "emp age - " then takes everything up to the next space (which should be the age you are looking for).  If the solution doesn't work for you, then the sample string provided doesn't exactly match your data - in which case you will need to tweak the answer to match the actual pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has built-in regular expression functions. If, as you say, the format is always the same, extracting the second group of numbers will give you the outcome you desire:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('Valid data: emp no - 123 emp age - 23 emp type - M.'
   2                   , '[0-9]+', 1, 2) as emp_age
   3  from dual
   4  /
EM
--
23

SQL>
```

These functions are covered in the documentation. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in Regular Expression functions.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @APC looks like you took my answer and extended it. Nice work.

Comment: I honestly don't know whether you're being sarcastic